# What ways do I have to stream openCV output to my own remote C++ gui?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opencv

So I have on one hand an embedded device with a camera running openCV and on the other hand a C++ (Qt) GUI. I would like to connect both i.e.:

- "stream" all the output image frames/video from openCV to my remote C++ gui
- send commands from my C++ gui to the embedded device

How can I do this, what possibilities do I have?  I was thinking about sockets, but I don't know whether that is the easiest solution to stream the image frames from openCV to my Qt gui.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you give us more details about what exactly you're trying to achieve? Do you want to stream data over a LAN network? Internet? A cabled connection? Do you need to stream actual video at 25 frames/second?

Answer (score 0):

You should give us more details about what you're trying to achieve.

### You say **"stream [...] to my remote C++ GUI"**: do you mean sending the data over a cabled connection? over a LAN network? over the Internet?

Depending on the answer this changes your system's architecture quite a bit. Especially in case you want to stream the data over the Internet. If your use case implies a LAN network, you can easily setup a peer-to-peer connection between the embedded device and the C++ app to send data. However, it's much more complicated if you want to send data over the Internet, because it is difficult to create a peer-to-peer connection if you don't have static IPs (which I'm assuming you do not have). You will need a server (which can be written with Qt as well) to work as a relay for sending data from the device to your C++ app.

### Do you need actual video streaming (at 25fps), or is a low refresh rate (1-0.5fps) sufficient ?

(I'm making the assumption you want to send data over a network)

Because if a low image rate is sufficient, using [WebSockets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocketserver.html) to send images on a regular basis might just do the trick.

Otherwise, you'll need to setup a [UDP connection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html#using-udp-with-qudpsocket) with a [video buffer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideobuffer.html).

Hope this helps!

D

Comment: Are you satisfied with my answer @hnrrhbmm ? If so, please accept it as answer. Otherwise let me know if you need further details. D